# Dynamic self-destructing image upload

Tags: web-apps, images

Is there any website that lets me upload an image and get an access link and makes the image dynamically inaccessible after a certain time?

What I mean by "dynamically" means that it should also remove the photo even if the page is still on.

Most of the websites I found let me upload a self destructing image. However, they get removed only if the user changes the page.

Comment: You might want to follow "Website Recommendation" proposal in here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation